# Can Roadhog's Chain Hook interrupt Reinhardt's Charge?

Tags: overwatch

Like the title says, can a Roadhog use his chain hook ability to interrupt an enemy Reinhardt's charge ability and prevent Reinhardt from smashing his ally into a wall?

Comment: As a caveat: if you hook someone who is being pinned by a friendly Reinhardt, Reinhardt's pin happens **before** your hook pulls them in. Your hook will still work, but this can result in pretty silly scenarios where Reinhardt pulls a hooked target halfway across the map over several seconds before they finally get pulled to you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Yes.**

The first thing Roadhog's hook does is stun the target briefly. The hook stops Reinhardt's charge and saves your teammate from taking the damage from striking a wall/object. Your teammate will still have taken the initial 50 damage from getting hit by the charge.